# Spring-integration scripting with Python

Tags: python, spring-integration, jython

I'm trying to use Python with spring-integration and jython-standalone-2.7.0:

Here is my application context:

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter id="in" channel="exampleChannel" >
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" />
    <int-script:script lang="python" location="script/message.py" />
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="exampleChannel" />
<int-ip:udp-outbound-channel-adapter id="udpOut" channel="exampleChannel" host="192.168.0.1" port="11111" />
```

Here is my script in Python:

```
print "Python"
message="python-message"
```

When I start the application, I see "Python" in the console.  This must mean that my script is launched by spring-integration but nothing is sent in udp.

I see in the code that in `org.spring.framework.integration.scripting.js223.AbstractScriptExecutor`:

```
result = scriptEngine.eval(script, new SimpleBindings(variables));
```

All the Python variables are in the Map variables and scriptEngine contains no reference to Python variables.

Thus, in `org.spring.framework.integration.scripting.js223.PythonScriptExecutor`:

```
scriptEngine.get(returnVariableName);
```

It returns null.

Is it a problem in Jython, in Spring-integration or may be I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I am not sure where the issue is, but I reproduced; investigating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Spring Integration; I have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3751).

```
        if (variables != null) {
            result = scriptEngine.eval(script, new SimpleBindings(variables));
        }
        else {
            result = scriptEngine.eval(script);
        }
```

When the first branch of the `if` test is taken, the result variable is added to the `SimpleBindings` object, and is not added to the engine scope map.

Even though, in your case, variables is empty, we still call the first branch.

**EDIT**:

Here is a work-around until we fix the bug...

```
public class Foo {

    private final ScriptExecutor executor = ScriptExecutorFactory.getScriptExecutor("python");

    private final ScriptSource source = new ResourceScriptSource(new ClassPathResource("/message.py"));

    public String script() {
        return (String) this.executor.executeScript(source);
    }

}
```

and

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter id="in" channel="exampleChannel" method="script">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" />
    <bean class="foo.Foo" />
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```